# Converting nested tuple 0 into row in matrix

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, pysam

I'm tring to make a code to simulation a wind turbine but it doesn't work, the error message that diplay said me that there is a worst tuple in my dictionnary but i've verified that several times but ther is no error. I need help.

Here is the code that i'm tring to execute :

`your text`import PySAM.Windpower as wp
`your text`import csv

`your text`# Create a Windpower object
`your text`wind_turbine = wp.default("WindPowerSingleOwner")

`your text`# Set the turbine parameters
`your text`wind_turbine.system_capacity = 200  # Turbine capacity in kW
`your text`wind_turbine.max_cp = 0.45  # Maximum power coefficient
`your text`wind_turbine.max_tip_speed = 80  # Maximum tip speed in m/s
`your text`wind_turbine.cut_in_speed = 3  # Cut-in wind speed in m/s
`your text`wind_turbine.cut_out_speed = 25  # Cut-out wind speed in m/s

`your text`def csv_to_dict(file_path):
result_dict = {}
with open(file_path, 'r') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
val = float(row['val'])
perc = float(row['perc'])
sel_perc = float(row['sel_perc'])
result_dict[val] = (perc, sel_perc)
return result_dict

`your text`# Provide the file path to your CSV file
`your text`csv_file_path = 'C:/Users/arthu/OneDrive/Documents/INTERNSHIP/SAM/05-07-`your text`2023/windSpeed.csv'

`your text`# Convert the CSV file to a dictionary
`your text`data_dict = csv_to_dict(csv_file_path)
`your text`print(data_dict)
#Set the wind resource data
`your text`wind_turbine.Resource.wind_resource_data = {
'fields': ['wind_speed', 'perc', 'sel_perc'],  # Field names representing wind `your text`speed, perc, and sel_perc
'heights': [0],  # Single height value since we have only one field
'wind_speed': [[float(key)] for key in data_dict],  # Wind speeds as a nested `your text`list
'perc': [[data_dict[key][0]] for key in data_dict],  # Perc as a nested list
'sel_perc': [[data_dict[key][1]] for key in data_dict]  # Sel_perc as a nested `your text`list
`your text`}

## Run the simulation

`your text`wind_turbine.execute()

## Access the wind turbine outputs

`your text`annual_energy = wind_turbine.Outputs.annual_energy

## Print the annual energy production

`your text`print("Annual Energy Production:", annual_energy, "kWh")*

When i execute this above code, it disply the following message error :

Cell In[25], line 32
30 print(data_dict)
31  #Set the wind resource data
---> 32 wind_turbine.Resource.wind_resource_data = {
33     'fields': ['wind_speed', 'perc', 'sel_perc'],  # Field names representing wind speed, perc, and sel_perc
34     'heights': [0],  # Single height value since we have only one field
35      'wind_speed': [[float(key)] for key in data_dict],  # Wind speeds as a nested list
36     'perc': [[data_dict[key][0]] for key in data_dict],  # Perc as a nested list
37     'sel_perc': [[data_dict[key][1]] for key in data_dict]  # Sel_perc as a nested list
38 }
40 # Run the simulation
41 wind_turbine.execute()

Exception: Error (-4) converting nested tuple 0 into row in matrix.

I will be very glad if someone could help me

I've decribed my problem in the previous content

Comment: Please edit/add the proper formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using dict instead of dict.keys!

Try using this instead of the wind_turbine.resource.wind_resource_data you're setting:

```
wind_turbine.Resource.wind_resource_data = {
    'fields': ['wind_speed', 'perc', 'sel_perc'],  # Field names representing wind speed, perc, and sel_perc
    'heights': [0],  # Single height value since we have only one field
    'wind_speed': [[float(key)] for key in data_dict.keys()],  # Wind speeds as a nested list
    'perc': [[data_dict[key][0]] for key in data_dict.keys()],  # Perc as a nested list
    'sel_perc': [[data_dict[key][1]] for key in data_dict.keys()]  # Sel_perc as a nested list
}
```